# Find the image of a Complex Function in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I want to find values of $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ so that

$$\Big|\frac{\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}}{2}\Big| < 1$$

or
$$\Big|\frac{\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}}{2}\Big| < 1$$

More generally, is there any theory in complex analysis as to how one might
solve $|f(z)| < c$?

I have tried thus far to solve for these inequalities, with success, in 
$\mathbb{R}$. I also tried to consider the equivalent inequality:

$$(\frac{\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}}{2})\overline{(\frac{\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}}{2})} < 1$$

but without success.

Comment: Both inequalities cannot hold at the same time, since multiplying them would give $1 \lt 1\,$. Do you mean each one separately?

Comment: Yes, I will clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;z_{1,2}=\frac{\lambda \pm \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}}{2}$ are the roots of $z^2 - \lambda z + 1 = 0\,$, so the problem is equivalent to determining $\lambda$ such that the equation has at least one root *strictly* inside the unit circle. But $z_1z_2=1$ by Vieta's formulas, so at least one of them has modulus $\le 1\,$, and the problem reduces to finding $\lambda$ such that *not* both roots are *on* the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you question reduces to finding the zeroes of $P(z)= z^2 +\lambda z+1$ inside the unit disk. With Rouche's theorem you can find the number of zeroes that lie inside the disk. The answer is that there is only one zero of $P(z)$ inside the disk when $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ lies inside the disk and zero otherwise.